# TFS 2012 Install Connection to Database Failure

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, database-connection, remote-server

I am attempting a install of TFS2012 on a remote server(we'll call it the dev server). The database I will be using (SQL Server 2008 R2) is on a separate server (db server). When I get to the connection screen I am getting an error.

Do you know if the admin account I use to log on to the dev server to install TFS needs to also have admin rights to the database I am connecting to? I currently, have a separate account that has access to the database. I have made sure that the port 1433 is open and allows remote connections. The Firewall has also been turned off and is not blocking this port.

There is a check box to use a preexisting empty database, but where would I specify that empty databases name?

(note- the servername is partly blacked out in the picture)
[image]

Comment: Are you able to connect via SQL Server Management Studio from any remote machine? This looks like TFS is not able to connect to SQL Server at all, let alone try to authenticate.